# Match a repeating digit (the same one) exactly two times in Javascript with RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm currently trying to match a repeating digit and so far I've got this:

```
pattern = /(\d){2}/
```

But when I test this pattern with a number of any length >= 2 it will return true. What I want to find is the following:
When I test the number 12344 it should return true and if the number is 12345 it should return false. But having a number of 12444 should also return false. I want to find the same digit repeated exactly twice.

EDIT: Thanks to anybody proposing a solution!

Comment: You have to think about word boundaries, and maybe even making sure that the characters before and after the selection are not digits

Comment: For numbers like `11222` should the output be `true` or `false`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox, not quite since I will always test a number, not a string with words and/or numbers mixed

Comment: @Rawing ha... tricky. I didn't even think of that. In this case it should still return true though. The answer I marked as the solution does exactly that.

Comment: @kidman01 you also only count consecutively repeated digits, right? So `1213` wouldn't be a match though `1` is repeated?

Comment: @SebastianProske yes exactly. I'm only interested in the consecutively repeated digits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For this kind of task you have to use lookarounds and backreferences:

```
(?:^|(.)(?!\1))(\d)\2(?!\2)
```

---

Explanation:

```
(?:         // match either...
    ^       // start of the string
|           // or...
    (.)     // any character
    (?!\1)  // not followed by the exact same character
)
(\d)        // then, match and capture a digit
\2          // and the same digit a 2nd time
(?!\2)      // and assert the digit doesn't show up a 3rd time
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like I expect it to. I just have to wrap my head around what is really going on here :D

Answer (score 1):

```
/(00|11|22|33|44|55|66|77|88|99)/
```

Comment: *But having a number of 12444 should also return false.*